# FullCalendar recurring events create duplicates BUG

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I found a bug in FullCalendar getEvents() method.
If I load events (and this is recurring event) and it falls on the last column (in week view), then Calendar::getEvents() return duplicated event on that day.

Here you can see in console: 
https://codepen.io/matthew_gates/pen/QWwdvMz?editors=1010

`Array(3)`

Does anyone else have such a problem?

Comment: This looks to be a duplicate of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57309795/fullcalendar-recurring-events-create-duplicates . So yes, it appears other people have a problem. In the comments on that question I suggested what needs to be done about it. We cannot deal with internal fullCalendar bugs here - AFAIK no-one here is a fullCalendar developer. We can help you with your implementation of fullCalendar and how to interact with it, but we can't answer anything about the internal code.

Comment: If you wish to report a new bug (or provide evidence / confirmation of an existing one) then (as per my comments on that other question) please visit https://fullcalendar.io/reporting-bugs and read the instructions in full.