# Fullcalendar.getEvents() doesn't return recurring events outside current view

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5, fullcalendar-6

According to the [`.getEvents()`](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-getEvents) documentation, it should return "all events in memory", but when having simple recurring events outside the current view, it doesn't.

No matter if they are dynamically added via `calendar.addEvent()` or are loaded with the `events`/ `initialEvents` option. It also happens with any view (I've tried `timeGrid`, `dayGrid` and `dayGridMonth`), while normal events not in the view *do* get returned as expected.

This behavior happens (at least) both in 5 (5.10.1 to be exact) and 6 (6.1.6).

Here is a reproducer, it's pretty simple but works like this: The calendar is initialized to Jan 2023 and then normal and recurring events are added in May and Jun so they are not showing in the current view.
`getEvents` returns the May one (the normal one) but not the recurrings.

```js
var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
  initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
  initialDate: '2023-01-01'
});
calendar.render();
console.log('Current View: ' + calendar.view.title)

console.log('Adding normal event')
calendar.addEvent({
  title: 'Normal Event',
  start: '2023-04-03T17:00:00',
  end: '2023-04-07T17:30:00'
})
console.log(`Found: ${calendar.getEvents().length}, 1 expected`)
console.log('Adding recurring event')
calendar.addEvent({
  title: 'Recurring Event',
  startTime: '17:00:00',
  endTime: '17:30:00',
  startRecur: '2023-06-07',
  endRecur: '2023-06-22',
  daysOfWeek: [3] // Wed
});
// Recurring events are expanded, so we expect 4, not 2. I can filter individual events based on the `defId`...
// ... if only I could get them
console.log(`Found: ${calendar.getEvents().length}, 4 expected!`)

calendar.gotoDate('2023-06-01')
console.log('Current View: ' + calendar.view.title)
console.log(`Found: ${calendar.getEvents().length}, 4 expected`)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fullcalendar/core@6.1.6/index.global.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fullcalendar/daygrid@6.1.6/index.global.min.js"></script>
<div id="calendar"></div>
```

There is [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57309795) regarding previous view-dependent bugs, but I'm surprised noone has run into this before. Is this behavior documented *anywhere* or am I correct in thinking this may be a bug?

I can muck around with the `eventStore`, but it can get *really* ugly when having multiple `eventSources`. Is there any API alternative to get **all** events? (ideally, unique ones i.e. the `defs` and not the `instances` themselves; but this is not a dealbreaker as I can filter them easily).

Comment: We can't really comment on whether the behaviour is intentional as (AFAIK) no-one here who watches the fullCalendar tag is actually a fullCalendar developer (and as you say, the documentation is not informative on this specific point). However it does feel like a bug, so I suggest going to https://fullcalendar.io/reporting-bugs